# Is there a way to get alternative of signature key of my android app

Tags: java, android

Just like getting signature of app ( which unfortunately is accessible from any other app and not my app only ) is there any secret key for every app that can't be returned expect from my app so I can use for anti modding

Comment: Please , for stackoverflow people, if my question is not asked well then tell me and not down it or close it , I just really need a help , I hate when my questions sometimes got deleted

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand what signing is for.  Signing, on an open platform, does not prevent other people from modifying data.  What signing does is authenticate that data is from a particular person.  But if I take your apk and resign it with my own key, I'm not claiming that this is an @ArabWare app, I'm claiming its my app.  It just so happens to have your code.  Signing does not prevent this.

The only way to make signing prevent this is to have a closed system-  to only allow certain people with certain signatures the ability to run software on it. Android is not a closed system. As such, signing cannot be used to prevent other people from resigning your app.

Comment: Brother ..  I have an algorithm that gets signature info of my app , like hash code etc..  but it can be easily gotten from any other app

Comment: My app is uploading the value of something like signature to a server and if it is not same as the put there it will not allow the app to do anything

Comment: But...... the modder can easily get my signature and edit the app and give the server a a direct value ( without getting codes )

Comment: I want something no one can access it else my app and if someone edits the app , it will be changed so no one can get the value

Comment: What you're asking for is mathematically impossible.  The user has your app.  There can't be anything in your app that the user can't get at, because he has the file.  You're trying to verify that an app is the one you expect-  you can't do that.  You can verify that a *user* is the one you expect, because he can have a shared secret (like a password) that isn't in the client app.  But there is no way to validate that a calling app at the other end of a webservice is who you think it is.  Even with a validated user, he can be using an unofficial client and there's no way to know for sure.